# displaying timer on tkinter home page window

Tags: python, tkinter

having problems adding a timer to my home page of my computer science nea project. im wanting the timer to display on the bottom left of the tkinter window home_page and cant seem to figure it out please could you advise me on how to fix this and what I've done wrong.
thank you Matthew.
code:
'''
having problems adding a timer to my home page of my computer science nea project. im wanting the timer to display on the bottom left of the tkinter window home_page and cant seem to figure it out please could you advise me on how to fix this and what I've done wrong.
thank you Matthew.
code:
'''

Comment: I think there is a formatting mistake; You probably forgot to add the code and instead of that in the code section you repeated your question.

Comment: this problem was few times on Stackoverflow - at least I wrote few time example with `root.after`  to run code which updates Label every 1 second

Answer (score 0):

here is example code for current time and date because you are missing code and I dont know what do you need exactly

example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, BOTTOM, NW
from datetime import datetime


now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
day = datetime.today()
today = day.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")
window.title('TEST')
title_label = Label(window, text="test window with time and date", font=('Courier', 10), fg='Red')
title_label.pack(pady=30)
time_label = Label(window, text=current_time, font=('Courier', 10))
time_label.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=NW)
date_label = Label(window, text=today, font=('Courier', 10))
date_label.pack(pady=30)
info_label = Label(window, text="time and date labels are visible", font=('Courier', 8))
info_label.pack(pady=30)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This will only show the _current_ time for at most one minute, and it doesn't add it at the bottom-left like the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was few times on Stackoverflow - I don't remember links  but at least I keep my answer on GitHub.

It uses `root.after()` to run function after 1 second which update time in `Label` and uses again `root.after()` to update again after 1 second.

I will not try to put it in bottom left of home_page - it is job for you.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

# --- functions ---

def update_time():
    label['text'] = time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d  %H:%M:%S')

    # run update_time again after 1000ms (1s)
    root.after(1000, update_time)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

# run update_time first time
update_time()  # at once
#root.after(1000, update_time)  # after 1 second

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: My GitHub [python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples) and [other examples with timer](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/timer-using-after)